# sudo script in my $HOME/bin folder

Tags: shell-script, sudo, path

I have a script in my `$HOME/bin` folder that must be executed with `sudo`.

If I run

```
sudo <nameofthescript>
```

I get

```
sudo: <nameofthescript>: command not found
```

What is the most preferable way to add this script to the `$PATH` of `sudo`?

Should I move it in `/usr/local/sbin`?

Should I create a `/root/bin` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` sets up a limited `PATH`, so it will not find your local script. You can configure it to not `env_reset` for a given user and so on, but perhaps the simplest thing is to write your own one-line `mysudo` script that does:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec sudo -s PATH="$PATH" exec "$@"
```

and then say `mysudo somecommand ...` instead of `sudo somecommand ...`. It will ask sudo to run a shell, set the `PATH` back to what it was, then run your command found in that original path.

Answer (score 1):

`PATH` is an environment variable on operating systems like Linux, Windows which has  specific set of directories where executable programs are located. According to your question, your executable script is placed under `$HOME/bin` directory. So if you want to run a script which is not in PATH, you need to give full file structural path to let OS reach the file to execute it. For example,

```
sudo $HOME/bin/<nameofthescript>
```

If you do not want to give full file path all the time, you can put that file path in environment veritable using below command. Consedering, you have kept your script in `$HOME/bin` directory.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Above command will add your bin directory to the environmental path and then you can use `<nameofscript>` from anywhere on the system.
Also, this will only work till the time your bash is running, if you try the same in new terminal, your PATH will change to default. To make it permanent, you need to add below line either in `$HOME/.profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc` file.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

To allow only root user to execute the `<nameofscript>` from anywhere, you can either put in under `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin` directory.